# Connection between Laplace's equation and hydrogenic electron Schrodinger equation

Tags: electrons, potential, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics

Consider Laplace's equation:

$\nabla ^2 V = 0$

This holds for an electric potential $V$ in a region of space where no charges are present. This includes a Coulomb potential of a hydrogen nucleus (outside the nucleus).

Solving this equation in spherical polar coordinates, for a separable potential of the form $V(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$ gives:

1. Radial equation with solution:

$R(r) = Ar^l + \frac{B}{r^{l+1}}$

2. Legendre equation for $\Theta(\theta)$. The angular part of the solutions for the potential is given by the spherical harmonics:

$\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi) = Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$.

Now consider the Time-Independent Schrodinger Equation for an electron orbiting a nucleus:

$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi-\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\psi = E\psi$

Solving this in spherical polar coordinates for separable eigenfunctions of the form $\psi_{n,l,m}(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$ gives:

1. A radial equation with general solutions of the form:

$R_{n,l}(r) = F(r)\frac{e^{-\frac{Zr}{na_0}}}{r}$

, where $F(r)$ is a power series of $r$ with an $l$ dependence. However, in the limit of small $r$, the radial equation for the electron TISE gives the same solutions as the potential radial equation:

$R(r) = Ar^l + \frac{B}{r^{l+1}}$

2. The radial part of the hydrogenic electron wavefunctions is also given by the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$, where the $\theta$ function is solved by the Legendre differential equation, which comes from the initial TISE.

My question is why do wavefunctions for an electron in a Coulomb potential have the same angular dependence as any electric potential function satisfying Laplace's equation. What is even the conceptual connection between a wavefunction and a potential field?

Also, why do the electron wavefunctions have the same angular dependence as the potential functions only in the small $r$ limit, where the centrifugal potential term in the TISE dominates the Coulomb and energy terms?

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian operator $\nabla^2$ can be written
$$\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+ \nabla_{\text{sphere}}^2\right], \qquad \nabla^2_{\text{sphere}}\equiv \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) + \frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}$$

where $\nabla^2_{\text{sphere}}$ is the Laplacian on the 2-sphere $\mathrm S^2$.  If we have an equation of the form $\big(\nabla^2 \psi\big)(r,\theta,\phi) = f(r)\psi$, then we may rearrange it as
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r^2\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\right)-r^2 f(r)\psi + \nabla_{\text{sphere}}^2 \psi =0$$

Separating $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)\rightarrow R(r)S(\theta,\phi)$ yields
$$\frac{1}{R(r)}\left[\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dR}{dr}\right) - r^2 f(r) R(r)\right] = -\frac{1}{S(\theta,\phi)}\left[\nabla_{\text{sphere}}^2 S(\theta,\phi) \right]= \lambda^2\tag{$\star$}$$
Solving both eigenvalue equations yields the set of radial and angular functions which can be combined together to yield the full solution.

---

> My question is why do wavefunctions for an electron in a Coulomb potential have the same angular dependence as any electric potential function satisfying Laplace's equation.

If we plug $f(r)=0$ into $(\star)$, we obtain the Laplace equation. If we plug $f(r) = E+\frac{\alpha}{r}$ into $(\star)$, we obtain the eigenvalue equation for the Coulomb Hamiltonian with eigenvalue $E$.  In both cases, the angular equation remains the same, and so the set of angular solutions (the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)) are the same in both cases.

> What is even the conceptual connection between [eigenfunctions of a Schrodinger-type Hamiltonian $H=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + V$] and a potential field?

They obey related differential equations as long as $V$ is only a function of $r$. If $V$ has angular dependence, the separation of variables performed above doesn't work.

> Also, why do the electron wavefunctions have the same angular [radial?] dependence as the potential functions only in the small $r$ limit, where the centrifugal potential term in the TISE dominates the Coulomb and energy terms?

In the limit of small $r$, $r^2f(r)\rightarrow 0$ and we recover the Laplace equation.